# how to check if number in vector is ODD or EVEN

Tags: r

Say you have:

```
vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Using if else statements, and a for loop - how can I check if the number is ODD in the if statement?

Comment: did you search for this? There are definitely many posts on how to do this.

Comment: `if (x %% 2 == 0){` search for modulus in R

Comment: this looks like homework.  Homework questions are allowed on SO, but you have to show us what you've tried so far and where you've gotten stuck; "please answer my homework" is unacceptable.  If this is **not** homework, could you provide more context (and in any case let us know what you've tried)?

Answer (score -2):

Let's rename the vector (as `vector`is a function) and define all odd numbers in a new vector `odd`and then subset `vector1`on those values that are contained in `odd`:

```
vector1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
odd <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
vector1[vector1 %in% odd]
[1] 1 3 5
```

If your vector contains multiple digit numbers, ou can use `grep`and regex to get the odd numbers:

```
vector2 <- c(1,27,32,44445,50,4,6666)
grep("\\d{0,}[13579]$", vector2, value = T)
[1] "1"     "27"    "44445"
```

You can use `grepl`to test which numbers are odd:

```
grepl("\\d{0,}[13579]$", vector2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If you need to use an `ifelse` statement to find out which numbers are odd and which are even, you can do this:

```
ifelse(grepl("\\d{0,}[13579]$", vector2), TRUE, FALSE)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```